# NameError when automatically loading a submodules

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have package structure like [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

```
sound/
├── effects
│   ├── echo.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── reverse.py
├── formats
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── waveread.py
│   └── wavewrite.py
└── __init__.py
```

Then  to automatically load the submodule `echo` and `reverse` I added the following import statement into my `effects/__init__.py` file

```
from . import echo
from . import reverse
```

However after I imported `sound.effects` I still have a NameError when trying to access `echo` and `reverse`:

```
>>> import sound.effects
>>> echo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'echo' is not defined
>>> reverse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'reverse' is not defined
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You imported `sound.effects`, but that doesn't bring the contents of `effects` into your current namespace. You still need to refer to them where they are: `sound.effects.echo` and `sound.effects.reverse`.

If you want to just refer to them by name, you need to import those names:

```
from sound.effects import echo, reverse
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. I know that I can import them like that but I want to take advantage of the fact that  *`__init__.py` can be used to execute initialization code*

Comment: No, you were perfectly clear. And you imported those names into `__init__.py`. But that doesn't make them available anywhere else. That is simply how Python works.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is how Python namespacing works.

Adding:

```
from . import echo
```

To `effect/__init__.py` imports the name `echo` into the `effect` namespace. When you import a module it executes the module code but in the module namespace not your main programs namespace.

In your example, you could access echo as `sound.effect.echo` or even import it (in your main file) as:

```
from sound.effect import echo
```